# MagicalRecord double values

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

i am using MagicalRecord to fetch my Objects.

I have got issue with findAllSortedBy.

Sometimes it returns double value with the same my object ID.

```
2014-12-04 15:01:46.254 A[13932:221016] ID: 0xd0000000052c0006 <x-coredata://3AB12137-72AE-4257-A0AF-45D81C322C2C/Document/p331> objID: 1160
2014-12-04 15:01:46.254 A[13932:221016] ID: 0xd0000000053c0006 <x-coredata://3AB12137-72AE-4257-A0AF-45D81C322C2C/Document/p335> objID: 1160
2014-12-04 15:01:46.254 A[13932:221016] ID: 0xd000000005300006 <x-coredata://3AB12137-72AE-4257-A0AF-45D81C322C2C/Document/p332> objID: 1097
2014-12-04 15:01:46.254 A[13932:221016] ID: 0xd000000005340006 <x-coredata://3AB12137-72AE-4257-A0AF-45D81C322C2C/Document/p333> objID: 1097
2014-12-04 15:01:46.254 A[13932:221016] ID: 0xd000000005280006 <x-coredata://3AB12137-72AE-4257-A0AF-45D81C322C2C/Document/p330> objID: 357
2014-12-04 15:01:46.254 A[13932:221016] ID: 0xd000000005380006 <x-coredata://3AB12137-72AE-4257-A0AF-45D81C322C2C/Document/p334> objID: 357
```

Comment: Maybe because you save it twice?

Comment: How are you putting these entities into your core data stack? Using magical record import? Creating entities and saving?

Comment: Yes, I am saving in context.

I don't know, why it is problem only for first time (sometimes), but second time all is ok.